# Spring Boot on Tomcat set file Paths in properties file

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat7, filepath, properties-file

I want to set my relative file path in a properties file so my SaxReader can pick it up when it runs on Tomcat server. I know this should be easy but I've forgotten forgive me :)

I know Spring Boot has application.properties file but I don't see a way to hook in here.

Is there a way to set the relative path in a properties file that will get picked up by Spring Boot and the SaxReader will see it?

As it is I'm hard coding just the filename and putting the file in the resources folder that serves up the templates and static content such as css and js files. The filePath system.out gives: org.dom4j.DocumentException **C:sts-bundle\sts-3.7.2.RELEASE\myFileName**  the toolsuite root location??? weird!!

Please tell me how to specify the relative path in a properties file.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the file path like any other string property in Spring Boot properties file and access it from inside the path.

E.g. I have the following set in my application.properties file:

`download.directory=temp`

and it is used as follows in java class:

```
@Value("${download.directory}")
private String downloadDirectory;
```

It is used to download the files, now, if I start the application with jar file present in let's say G:/applications folder then the files will be downloaded into G:/applications/temp.